# object movement has unwanted increase in speed using setTimeout inside setInterval

Tags: javascript

I'm testing movement for a practice game I'm working on, what I'm trying to get going with is a loop that will run twice (because the object is a rabbit) inside of an interval so that the object won't move in a continuous circle and it'll have uniqueness to it. How I'm executing it is the interval will run every 1500 miliseconds and the timeout (inside the interval) will run in half of that time to create the rabbit moving in one direction twice instead of once. The problem is after some time the bunny will take larger steps forword and do so faster. I'm not completely sure what the problem is, thank you for looking at this. Heres my code

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var wabbits = {
  wabbit1: {
    x: 200,
    y: 200,
    w: 10,
    h: 10,
    speed: 2,
    moving: "",
    dead: false,
    updateInterval: 2000
  }
};
  //make it easier to type out the object
  var bunny = wabbits.wabbit1;

var movement = ["up", "down", "left", "right"];
var left = "left";
var up = "up";
var down = "down";
var right = "right";

var update = setInterval(function(){
  draw();
}, 1);

canvas.style.backgroundColor = "green";

function draw(){
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.fillStyle = "grey";
  context.fillRect(bunny.x, bunny.y, bunny.w, bunny.h);
  context.fill();
  border();
}

function border(){
  if(bunny.x <= 0){
    bunny.x += bunny.speed * 2;
  }
  if(bunny.x >= 490){
    bunny.x -= bunny.speed * 2;
  }
  if(bunny.y <= 0){
    bunny.y += bunny.speed * 2;
  }
  if(bunny.y >= 490){
    bunny.y -= bunny.speed * 2;
  }
}

function bunny1move(){
 if(!wabbits.wabbit1.dead){
  var randM = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 0;
  wabbits.wabbit1.moving = movement[randM];
  function mv(){
   switch(wabbits.wabbit1.moving){
    case "up":
     wabbits.wabbit1.y -= wabbits.wabbit1.speed;
    break;
    case "down":
     wabbits.wabbit1.y += wabbits.wabbit1.speed;
    break;
    case "left":
     wabbits.wabbit1.x -= wabbits.wabbit1.speed;
    break;
    case "right":
     wabbits.wabbit1.x += wabbits.wabbit1.speed;
    break;
    default: 
     console.log("something in bunny1.mv() is not working properly, err: " + wabbits.wabbits1.moving);
    break;
   };
   if(wabbits.wabbit1.y <= 0){
    wabbits.wabbit1.y += wabbits.wabbit1.speed * 2;
    wabbits.wabbit1.moving = down;
   }
   if(wabbits.wabbit1.y >= 758){
    wabbits.wabbit1.y -= wabbits.wabbit1.speed * 2;
    wabbits.wabbit1.moving = up;
   }
   if(wabbits.wabbit1.x <= 0){
    wabbits.wabbit1.x += wabbits.wabbit1.speed * 2;
    wabbits.wabbit1.moving = right;
   }
   if(wabbits.wabbit1.x >= 1356){
    wabbits.wabbit1.x -= wabbits.wabbit1.speed * 2;
    wabbits.wabbit1.moving = left;
   }
      //make mv repeat twice
   this.setTimeout(mv, wabbits.wabbit1.updateInterval / 2);
  }
  mv();
  
 }
}
//update the movement function
setInterval(bunny1move, wabbits.wabbit1.updateInterval);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="500px" width="500px"></canvas>
```

Comment: I don't see how this "*makes mv repeat twice*" - every `mv()` call schedules it again. Why would it stop after the second time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You immediately invoke mv after creating it in bunny1move, but after each call to mv it sets a timeout to call itself again one second later. After it gets called again it sets a new timeout to call itself after the next second, and so on. This chain of calls extends ad infinitum.

This by itself wouldn't be too bad, actually it seems like it would be what you want, to have mv called every second. The problem happens when you call bunny1move every two seconds, each of these repeating calls to bunny1move creates a new chain of mv's and they all stack on top of the previous chains.

So it's not so much that the bunny is moving farther on each iteration, it's that more and more mv chains are being created, and they are all being called in sync, making it look like a longer jump when really it's just many more little jumps.

If you put a console.log statement at the end of mv you can see this increase in mv calls over time.

You should just be able to get rid of mv altogether, then call setInterval on bunny1move for every second:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var wabbits = {
  wabbit1: {
    x: 200,
    y: 200,
    w: 10,
    h: 10,
    speed: 2,
    moving: "",
    dead: false,
    updateInterval: 2000
  }
};
  //make it easier to type out the object
  var bunny = wabbits.wabbit1;

var movement = ["up", "down", "left", "right"];
var left = "left";
var up = "up";
var down = "down";
var right = "right";

var update = setInterval(function(){
  draw();
}, 1);

canvas.style.backgroundColor = "green";

function draw(){
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.fillStyle = "grey";
  context.fillRect(bunny.x, bunny.y, bunny.w, bunny.h);
  context.fill();
  border();
}

function border(){
  if(bunny.x <= 0){
    bunny.x += bunny.speed * 2;
  }
  if(bunny.x >= 490){
    bunny.x -= bunny.speed * 2;
  }
  if(bunny.y <= 0){
    bunny.y += bunny.speed * 2;
  }
  if(bunny.y >= 490){
    bunny.y -= bunny.speed * 2;
  }
}

function bunny1move(){
 if(!wabbits.wabbit1.dead){
  var randM = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 0;
  wabbits.wabbit1.moving = movement[randM];
  switch(wabbits.wabbit1.moving){
   case "up":
    wabbits.wabbit1.y -= wabbits.wabbit1.speed;
   break;
   case "down":
    wabbits.wabbit1.y += wabbits.wabbit1.speed;
   break;
   case "left":
    wabbits.wabbit1.x -= wabbits.wabbit1.speed;
   break;
   case "right":
    wabbits.wabbit1.x += wabbits.wabbit1.speed;
   break;
   default: 
    console.log("something in bunny1.mv() is not working properly, err: " + wabbits.wabbits1.moving);
    break;
  };
  if(wabbits.wabbit1.y <= 0){
   wabbits.wabbit1.y += wabbits.wabbit1.speed * 2;
   wabbits.wabbit1.moving = down;
  }
  if(wabbits.wabbit1.y >= 758){
   wabbits.wabbit1.y -= wabbits.wabbit1.speed * 2;
   wabbits.wabbit1.moving = up;
  }
  if(wabbits.wabbit1.x <= 0){
   wabbits.wabbit1.x += wabbits.wabbit1.speed * 2;
   wabbits.wabbit1.moving = right;
  }
  if(wabbits.wabbit1.x >= 1356){
   wabbits.wabbit1.x -= wabbits.wabbit1.speed * 2;
   wabbits.wabbit1.moving = left;
  }
 }
}
//update the movement function
setInterval(bunny1move, wabbits.wabbit1.updateInterval / 2);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="500px" width="500px"></canvas>
```

As an aside, you should consider posting this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . They should have a few constructive comments on better ways to design your program for more flexibility, extendability, readability etc.

Comment: Thank you! I'll definately look into codereview because being that I've been looking for new ways to engineer my code I think this'll be a perfect oppertuinity for me! I might have also gained some words of wisdom from what you put about little hops just becomming big hops too!

Comment: Code Review will only accept code that works as intended. If it doesn't, it will get closed. Obvious bugs like these would be grounds for closure. Please refer to their [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead of the main site and read it yourself before sending anyone else that way.

Comment: @Mast I am aware of the guidelines for posting a code review. The code works as the author intended, other than the specific bug already addressed. That being said, there are many opportunities for growth here, which is why they should post a code review.

Comment: "The problem is after some time the bunny will take larger steps forword and do so faster. I'm not completely sure what the problem is" That's not 'working as intended' IMO.